# Scroll Through Divs using Z-index

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have say 3 divs all positioned at 0,0px on top of each other.

Div 1 (Z-Index:0)
Div 2 (Z-Index:1)
Div 3 (Z-Index:2)

How would i changed the order after every 30seconds so it sort of loops through all divs (using ID tag).  So after 30 seconds, Div 2 is at the top and Div one at the bottom, then after 30 seconds, div 3 is at the top and Div 2 at the bottom etc...

Comment: Is there logic to the rearrangement of the divs?

Comment: You would have a lot more luck using a CSS framework that will do the work for you. You are referring to something similar to an image carousel. Try out Bootstrap or Foundation or even W3CSS and utilize jquery to accomplish this. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a framework or anything like that. This is actually very simple. Here is a quick demo that is using jQuery as a lib, but if needed you could do this all vanilla as well.

https://jsfiddle.net/jL2youk6/

All you need to do is set an interval and increment an index and select the div at that index and assign an 'active' class or something that only has a set z-index.

```js
var $box = $('.box'),
  active_box = 0,
  time = 30000;

setInterval(function() {

  // Check out active box index
  if (active_box < $box.length - 1) {
    active_box++
  } else {
    active_box = 0;
  }
  
  // Set the active and remove active from siblings
  $box.eq(active_box).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')

}, time);
```

```css
.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  z-index: 0;
}

.active {
  z-index: 2;
}

#a {
  background-color: red;
}

#b {
  background-color: blue;
}

#c {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='box active' id='a'>1</div>
<div class='box' id='b'>2</div>
<div class='box' id='c'>3</div>
```

Comment: That works on fiddle but not when i put it on my site.  I add the style elements in the div itself not using <style>

Comment: @user2899094 You shouldn't do inline styles. You need to have those styles be external in order for this to work properly.